# Windows File Explorer - Images - Dimension Units

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, images, dimensions

Does anyone know, when looking at images through file explorer, the unit of measurement that windows displays as a dimensions?

It does not appear to be pixels.

Anyone?
[image]

Comment: What makes you think it's *not* pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at file properties (right button over the file, properties), Detail tab, Image section, fields : dimensions (pixels), width(pixels), height(pixels), horizontal resolution(dots per inch) and vertical resolution (dots per inch).

Answer (score 2):

Those would be pixels as far as I'm aware.  I've never seen them be anything else.

Comment: Thats what I thought. But I create a 200x200px box in adobe illustrator. I export this image as a high quality bmp. When I view this through explorer, it appears to be 838x838. Same issue with the image in my OP. The image was like 777x999px but when exported, it displays as 1655x905.

Comment: That would probably be because AI is doing a conversion based on DPI as well, which will create a large image.  Because if you print a 200x200 image at 300 DPI it'll be different than printing the same image at 1200 DPI.